# ¿Como resuelvo en SQL 'The query can not be executed. It is too complex. Only “COUNT(*)” is supported'?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ciencia-de-datos, libreoffice-calc

estoy intentando ejecutar el QUERY:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM VENTAS_2020 WHERE Producto='Bocina' AND Valor>600 AND Año>=2019;
```

en Base (de LibreOffice 7.0) y me salta un error diciendo: The query can not be executed. It is too complex. Only “COUNT(*)” is supported. ¿Alguien tiene experiencia trabajando en LibreOffice y con este error en particular?

Ademas si ejecuto:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventas WHERE Producto='Bocina' AND Valor>600 AND Año>=2019;
```

Me funciona correctamente, pero obviamente quiero poder mandarle el argumento adecuado a COUNT(). Dejo adjunta la img de la tabla en cuestión: [image: ventas]

Comment: Pero el resultado de `COUNT(ID)` y `COUNT(*)` es el mismo. ¿Dónde está el problema?

Comment: Hola @RogerTorné, me piden sacar el cuadrado de 2 y mi software solo me permite hacer 2+2, y alguien me dice: -El resultado de 2+2 y 2^2 es el mismo ¿cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

No le veo problema, pues el resultado lo esta dando con el COUNT(*), no tendrás inconveniente al hacer esa consulta, por otra parte deberia de agregar un GROUP BY para agrupar los resultados de acuerdo a algun tipo producto

Comment: ESo depende, si quiere un conteo único entonces el grupo by no es necesario

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Como le decía a @RogerTorné que comentó la pregunta, no me sirve que la manera general me funcione pues lo que realmente quiero hacer es COUNT(DISTINCT ID), es decir sin contar repetidos. En el caso de una DB real, si duplicamos la última fila, el query con COUNT(*) me va a lanzar 3! lo cual para mis fines es incorrecto. Con COUNT(DISTINCT ID) me lanzaría 2. Pero por alguna razón no puedo ejecutarlo :'(

Comment: Pero de que manera detectarias la fila duplicada, es porque creas un registro mas, lo que equivale a un producto mas.

Comment: @JaimeHerrera Si la detecto o no el hecho es que está en mi DB. Sería un error contarla ya que es un error de registro

Comment: Pero que condicion pondrias en la bae, algun campo validador, asi pones en el WHERE esa validacion y ya te funcionaria perfecto el COUNT(*)